# Undo and Redo functionalities missing in Stickies

Tags: macos, stickies

I've accidentally edited an existing note in Stickies.app and found that command + z is not working? Is there any available functionality in the Stickies app for undo or to restore lost work?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Unfortunately, your question isn't clear. If by _Sticky Notes_ you mean the Stickies application include with macOS, then Command+Z does work. If you mean "Sticky Notes" the Windows app, then this isn't the right place to ask. And, if you mean something else (perhaps some other app you've downloaded), we need you to clarify for us. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer. For now, can you please edit your question (there's an _edit_ link below it) to clarify?

Comment: Edited hope it's much clearere